# Find the general solution of equation $\cot x+\tan x=2$

Tags: trigonometry

My approach:
$$\cot x +\tan x = (1+\tan^2x)/\tan x = 2$$
$$\sec^2x+\tan x= 2$$
$$1/(\sin x\cos x) = 2$$
$$\sin^2x +\cos^2x =2\sin x\cos x$$
$$(\sin x -\cos x)^2=0$$
$$\sin x =\cos x$$
So, $x = n\pi+(\pi/4)$. This was my answer. But the answer given is $x = 2n\pi\pm\pi/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\cot(x) = 1 / \tan(x)$. Take random letter, let $a = \tan (x)$.

Then it is $$1/a + a = 2$$

$$1 + a^2 = 2a$$

$$a^2 - 2a + 1 = 0$$

$$(a-1)^2 = 0$$
$$a - 1 = 0$$

$$a = 1$$

$$\tan(x) = 1$$

Then you can finish!

Comment: But the answer is x = 2nπ ± π/3.

Answer (score 1):

*Hmm, wrong reduction to algebraic form.*
$$\tan x\equiv u\implies u+1/u=2\implies u=1$$
$$u=1\implies x=n\pi+\frac\pi4$$

Comment: But the answer is x = 2nπ ± π/3.

Comment: @Sangeeta Your working's wrong, and the given answer is also wrong...

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is enough to consider $x\gt 0.$ By AM-Gm inequality $$\dfrac{\cot x+\tan x}{2}\ge\sqrt{\cot x\tan x}=1$$ for all $x\notin\{n\pi/2\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and equality occur when $$\cot x=\tan x,$$ which implies $x\in\{n\pi+\pi/4\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$